# Error while using Bootstrap DateTime Picker

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I'm trying to use bootstrap datetime picker.
I include all minimal requires :
CSS :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bundles/app/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
```

JS :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bundles/app/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/master/locale/it.js"></script>
<script src="bundles/app/console/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://accounts.tao.tw.shuttle.com/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/transition.js"></script>
```

Then i add the html :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

But if i click on input text nothing happen and datetime picker doesn't work.
I'm sure that all CSS and js file are loaded succesfully.
Anyone know how datetime picker work?
Thanks.

Comment: Is bootstrap locally installed? I suspect these link `bundles/app/js/bootstrap.js` and `bundles/app/console/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.

Comment: I add this 2 file in my public folder in symfony. What you suspect? Bootstrap dropdown for example work.

Comment: Can you open the browser console, see the log, it should tell you something.

Comment: Console doesn't say me anything, no error, no warning

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your imports, use this one instead:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </div>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why if i copy and run on my webpage it doesn't work? Console return me $ is not defined.

Comment: How can I know if you don't get any errors.. try to create a new file on your desktop and copy paste this code there. then open it in your browser.

Comment: if it tells you '$ is not defined' that means jquery has not loaded successfully. try to clear your browser cache and refresh the page.

Comment: it may take sometime to load all the imports, be patient. in your browser make sure all the files have been loaded successfully.

Comment: All file is loaded but still doesn't work. If i click on input nothing happens.

Comment: did you try another browser? which one are you using?

Comment: Use Chrome instead and run this code alone and see whether it works.

Comment: Make sure that Firefox allows running scripts, otherwise, it won't work. have you tried with Chrome or IE?

Comment: Yeah, my config of Firefox allow to execute js.

Comment: With IE I have all page blank.

Comment: Are you using the same computer that could show the page here?

Comment: Yes...and the same browser.

Comment: this is a strange behaviour :~

Comment: Anyway, this code works, there is something wrong with your browsers. maybe you could try it on another computer.

Comment: I will try and i will let you know. Thanks